# Java: Parsing a String and breaking it up into 'terms'

Tags: java, string, parsing

I'm having trouble on a project revolving around chemical formula. I have two classes, Term and Formula.

Term receives inputs such as 'H' or 'C2' - with only a single letter and any number of following numbers. Its' fields are element and atoms - element stores character of the element, 'H' or 'C', and atoms stores the int value of the number of atoms, 1 or 2.

I wrote the constructor as such;

```
public Term(String s)
    {

        if(s.length() == 1){
            element = s.charAt(0);
            atoms = 1; }

        else {
            element = s.charAt(0);
            String sA = s.substring(1,s.length());
            atoms = Integer.parseInt(sA);
        }
    }
```

I understand that. My problem is in the class Formula, that receives Strings like "CH3CH2CH2CH2CH2CH3". It involves an ArrayList that stores Term objects called terms. I need to write a constructor that can receive a formula such as
"CH2O", and would give the terms {Term('C',1),Term('H',2),Term('O',1)} etc.

I'm really struggling with figuring out how to make the constructor identify the terms within the input String - I've thought about valueOf and indexOf, or may substring, but can't seem to get it. My first attempt was;

```
 terms = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i <= s.length();i++)
    { 
        if ((Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i))) &&  (Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i+1)))
        { Term formulaS = new Term(s.charAt(i));
            terms.add(formulaS); }
```

I understand its very wrong and only identifies terms that only have a character, but not number of atoms, such as 'H'. I have a feeling the answer involves the for loop. I apologize for the length of the post, but any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You need to look into [lexical analysis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis), which is the process of breaking up a sequence of characters into meaningful "tokens" based on a [lexical grammar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_grammar), usually defined by regular expressions.

Comment: You could probably just uppercase the entire input string immediately. Then you wouldn't have to do any uppercase checking. You'll also need to do a few things different in your for loop. Firstly, you're going too far. Should be i < s.length. And you're going to have to not check i + 1, if you're at the last character in the string. I'd perhaps use a while loop for this instead of a for. But it CAN be done with a for, but you probably just want to store the characters until you hit a valid number, and THEN do your term addition. Or use a regular expression to break it up for you.

Comment: Will you need to handle 2 letter atom names, like `"Na"` and `"Cl"`?  Or is it guaranteed you will only be given molecules composed of atoms with only one character symbols?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a job for regular expression parsing using [`java.util.Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`java.util.Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).  In particular, you'll want to make the regex specify groups, so you can access each `Term` as a group via the [`group()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-) method on `Matcher`.

Here is code that parses your input molecule and instantiates `Term` objects. I've fleshed it out from the original with some very helpful suggestions from [@AJNeufeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3690024/ajneufeld).

```
public class MoleculeParser {
    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile ("([A-Z][a-z]?)(\\d*)");

    public static List<Term> parseMolecule (String molecule) {
        List<Term> terms = new ArrayList<> ();

        Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher (molecule);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String element = matcher.group(1);
            String group2 = matcher.group(2);
            if (!group2.isEmpty ()) {
                int atoms = Integer.parseInt (matcher.group(2));
                terms.add(new Term(element, atoms));
            }
            else {
                terms.add(new Term(element));
            }
        }

        return terms;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String str = "CH3CH2CH2CH2CH2CH3";
        System.out.println (parseMolecule (str));

        str = "C12H22O11 ";
        System.out.println (parseMolecule (str));

        str = "SiCl4";
        System.out.println (parseMolecule (str));
    }    
}


public class Term {
    public Term (String element) {
        this(element, 1);
    }

    public Term (String element, int atoms) {
        _element = element;
        _atoms = atoms;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return _element + (_atoms != 1 ? _atoms : "") ;
    }

    private String _element;
    private int _atoms;
}
```

This code leverages the power of regex groups to not only solve your immediate issue, but also handle the parsing that you were doing inside of `Term`, and also support atoms with two characters in their periodic symbol.

A regex "group" is a piece of a regex match that you can then refer to by index.  So regexes can be used not only to test whether the full input expression matches, but also to parse the matched input expression and break it up into pieces that match pieces of the regex itself - i.e. groups. You use parentheses to define groups in a regex - please be sure to review all the tutorial links I mention at the bottom of this post so that you understand this fully.

In the code above, the regex `Matcher` iterates through your input.  Each chunk it encounters with `find()` matches the set of groups specified in the regex.  Group `0` is always the entire matching set of groups, group `1` is the first group, and group `2` is the second. Since the second group (atoms) is optional, we test for whether it's empty.  Please also note that the `Pattern` compilation should only happen once, hence its instantiation as a `static final` constant.

The main takeaway here is that we've pulled all the parsing out of `Term` and centralized everything in this one parsing routine. To support this, I rewrote the `Term` constructors for you.

Understanding regular expressions is essential for any kind of parsing.  I recommend [the Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) for a good Java-based introduction. In particular, make sure you understand [the section on groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html), since that is what we are leveraging above to break up your molecule.

As @AJNeufeld points out in the comments, my solution will not support more complex molecules like Al2(SO4)3.  With an understanding of this code and the cited tutorials, you should be able to modify it to support such input.

Comment: I'd use `\\d*` ... You could get "sugar" ... C12H22O11 ... multiple digits after each atom.

Comment: Agreed - thanks.  Am working on this and support for all the elements with names longer than one letter (i.e. most of them).

Comment: Excellent!  May I further suggest `(([A-Z][a-z]?)(\\d*))`, so that `group(1)` is the whole term, `group(2)` is the atomic symbol, and `group(3)` is either the count (or an empty string implying "1").

Comment: Thanks!  I will suggest that above, then the OP can decide whether they want to modify the `Term` constructor or not to take advantage of this.  (BTW my excuse for originally not using `\\d*` is that I was never that good in orgo :-) )

Comment: Also, I'd move `Pattern pattern = ...` outside of the method, and make it a `final static`.  No point recompiling it every molecule; it is the same pattern. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I originally just wanted it to be a test program that OP could run and then adapt from, but I think it makes sense to do as you say since OP would benefit from seeing that too.  Working on it now...

Comment: It was either poking and prodding you, or writing a competing answer; this was easier ;-)

Comment: @epill11 - Note that using `Matcher#find()` will skip over unrecognized characters. "Al2(SO4)3" will be parsed only as "Al2", "S", and "O4".  The parenthesis and "3" will all be ignored.

Comment: Agreed - I'll put that as a caveat and leave it to the OP to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in assuming you need a `for` loop. Your `for` loop is actually very close to correct. The only problem is that you're only add `if` the current character is a letter **and** the next character is also a letter. If you change it as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length();i++) { 
  if ((Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i)))) { // If current character is a letter
    if (Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i+1))) {
        // If the next char is also letter, add current only
        terms.add(new Term(s.substring(i,i+1)));
      } else {
        // If next char is number, add both
        terms.add(new Term(s.substring(i,i+2)));
      }
  } 
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Oldschool but reliant:

```
static void lex(String s) {
    String token = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (token.length() > 0 && !Character.isDigit(c)) {
            System.out.println(token);
            token = "";
        }
        token += c;
    }

    if (!token.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(token);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that creates an ArrayList by parsing terms. It could also handle terms with a second lower case character if you update the Term constructor.

```
    public ArrayList<Term> initList(String initString) {
    ArrayList<Term> terms = new ArrayList<Term>();
    int nextTerm = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < initString.length();i++)
    { 
        while(i < initString.length() && 
              !Character.isUpperCase(initString.charAt(i))) {
            i++;
        }
        // parse the next term from the nextTerm start index to the current i index
        terms.add(new Term(initString.substring(nextTerm, i)));
        nextTerm = i;
    }
    return terms;
}
```